# Long <table> in aspx page - not correct print layout in IE9

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an aspx page that I want to use as printing version of the account of a registered person in my application.

In that page I have the following code that basically includes a very long table that extends to more than one A4 page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PrintAccountDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="protected_PrintAccountDetails" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Print Account Details</title>

</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">


    <asp:Panel runat="server" Width="210mm" Style="margin: 0 auto;">
      <br /><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Font-Underline="True">Financial Information -Trading Experience</asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Font-Underline="False" Font-Bold="True">Answers on questionnaire</asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 70%">
                        <ul>
                            <li id="q66" runat="server">Main Shareholders - partners - members with more than 25%
                                share - 1</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 30%">
                       <%= PrintAnsw66.Trim() %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li id="q67" runat="server">Main Shareholders - partners - members with more than 25%
                                share - 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= PrintAnsw67.Trim() %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                  .
                  .(Many more <tr>s of two cells)
                  .
                  .
               </table>
     </asp:Panel>
</body>
```

When I try to print that page in IE9 the tr that is close to the page break does not print correctly. The tr that happens to be close to the page break has its 2d cell in the previous page while the 1st cell of the SAME row in the page that is should be.
In FF and in Chrome every row of the table even the ones in the page break is printed together with no weird behavior.

Does anyone have an idea on what could be the problem and how can i fix it ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to replace the table with divs.

The reason is that if the table is break (when explorer try to prints it), then the results can not be as you like, but the divs can be break in one line of them with out change the view of them when they continue on next page.

I see that your table is actually two columns 70%-30%, and so its easy to make it with divs.

here some examples:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-2-column.htm
http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/ 
http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/design-2-column-layout.shtml

Comment: I've managed to find a solution to my problem with a combination of divs and the use of page-breaks of css. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is IE9 rendering issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/e6f49d52-ec3f-47c5-802e-b80d1a58ed39/

I can't find the link to ticket, but it exist.

To fix this issue you need to remove all spaces and line breaks between your table element end tags and the start of the next table cell.  In other words, make the td, tr on the same line, right next to each other with NO spaces in between.